# getting UNDEFINED value AJAX JSON

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am getting `undefined` alerted when i run this code, what seems to be causing the problem?

this is my insert_home.php

```
else if(isset($_POST['SELECTSLIDE']))
{
$SSID = ($_POST['SELECTSLIDE']);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *FROM slider SLIDE_NUM=('$SSID')");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo json_encode(array("a" => $row['SLIDE_TITLE']));

}
 mysqli_close($con); 
}
```

and this is my javascript

```
function SLIDE_EDIT(SLIDEID)
{

$.post('insert_home.php',{SELECTSLIDE:SLIDEID}).done(function(data){
     alert(data.a);
    });

}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you checked the HTTP response (use the browser's developer tools' net tab) to see if it is what you expect? Is the data right? Is the Content-Type right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX JSON format is wrong, you should assign query fetch result in array and after that use json_encode function to return valid JSON
LIKE this

```
else if(isset($_POST['SELECTSLIDE']))
    {
    $response = array();
    $SSID = ($_POST['SELECTSLIDE']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *FROM slider SLIDE_NUM=('$SSID')");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         array_push($response, array("a" => $row['SLIDE_TITLE']));
    }
     header('Content-type: text/json');
     echo json_encode($response); 
     mysqli_close($con); 
    }
```

And in JavaScript, use for loop to get values, like

```
function SLIDE_EDIT(SLIDEID)
{

$.post('insert_home.php',{SELECTSLIDE:SLIDEID}).done(function(data){
     for(var i in data){
        alert(data[i].a);
      }
    });

}
```

Comment: You should also `exit()` or `die()` unless you're happy that something could upset that JSON's validity after it's been outputted.

Comment: Right @Popnoodles, exit() or die() would be useful, thanks

Comment: Walanjo ang GALENG! HAHA